# 'Continuity' necessary in proof dynamical systems?

Tags: continuity, dynamical-systems, proof-explanation, lipschitz-functions

The following is a (rough) translation of a statement and proof given during a course in dynamical systems.

*Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be and open set, $f: D \to \mathbb{R}: (t, x) \mapsto D(t,x)$ a continuous function such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ (exists and) is continuous. Then $f$ is locally Lipschitz with respect to $x$.*

**Proof** For $(\tau, \gamma) \in D$, since $D$ is open, pick a compact, convex neighbourhood $U$ of $(\tau, \gamma)$ such that $U \subseteq D$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(U)$ is compact, thus has some upper bound $C > 0$. Pick any $(t,x), (t, x') \in U$. By the Lagrange mean value theorem there exists some $x'' \in [x, x']$ such that
$$
\vert f(t,x) - f(t,x')\vert \leq \vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x'')\vert \vert x - x' \vert \leq C \vert x - x' \vert
$$
showing that $f$ is indeed Lipschitz with respect to $x$ after restricting to some neighbourhoud of $(\tau, \gamma)$. This by definition means that $f$ is locally Lipschitz with respect to $x$. (QED)

I might be mistaken - multivariate calculus was a few years ago - but surely the continuity of $f$ was not used (and thus not needed) in this proof? If that's true, why would my professor have included it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The continuity of $f$ is a consequence of the statement that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ (exists and) is continuous on $D$. For a function to be differentiable --to be more precise, for its derivative to exist / to be well defined-- everywhere in $D$, it is necessary for $f$ to be (at least!) continuous. See also [the relevant Wikipedia lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Continuity_and_differentiability).

As you noted, the differentiability or continuity of $f$ in the $t$-direction is never used. However, the continuity of $f$ in $t$ follows from the larger context. That is, we want to make sure that the dynamical system
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} = f(x,t)
\end{equation}
makes sense in some way. If $f$ is not continuous in $t$, this implies that $\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d} t}$ is not continuous in $t$. This means that $x(t)$ is not *continuously* differentiable.

This does not immediately cause problems, but for a large number of results in dynamical systems theory, it is necessary to be able to assume that an orbit $x(t)$ is continuously differentiable in $t$. However, it is very well possible (and quite interesting, too) to relax the continuity assumption of $f$ in the $t$-direction, and see how previous results can be extended.

Comment: **False**: $f(x,y) = \chi_{\Bbb Q}(y)$ is discontinuous in every point of $\Bbb R^2$ but $\partial f/\partial x = 0$  in every point of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: As indicated in the answer, I discuss the continuity and differentiability in $x$, which is the relevant function variable for the Lipschitz result quoted in the question.

Comment: Hmm, when I say that a function is continuous, then I mean to say that it is continuous in all its variables (of course, continuity in the second variable is obvious in this case and perhaps this is what my professor meant). You agree then, that continuity in $t$ is not required?

Comment: My counterexample is Lipschitz in $x$. The existence and continuity of *one* partial derivative implies nothing on the continuity of the function. The existence of partial derivatives is strictly weaker than the differentiability of the function.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, I see the confusion now.

Comment: @Bib-lost, the continuity of $f$ isn't required for the lemma but will be used in the proof of the main theorem.

Comment: Interestingly, continuity of $f$ in $t$ is not necessary to prove existence and uniqueness of solutions to $\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} = f(x,t)$. For more information, see J.D. Meiss, *Differential Dynamical Systems*, ch. 3.6, exercise 8 on page 103. Well spotted, @Bib-lost.

Comment: I guess I just inherited my algebra professor's attitude of 'always prove everything in the most general context possible'. ;-) Thank you for your answer and time!